# Scorm 2004 score values are not coming in after a quiz

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I am trying to write a JavaScript integration for Scorm 2004 and I added the following code to intercept any score value. I go to a quick and there is no score value coming in.

```
SetValue = (name, value) => {
   // see if name is 'cmi.score.min|max|raw|scaled'
}
```

My goal is to get score value and send it to back-end, I am wondering when the score values will be available? is it possible there can be a quiz without score value coming in (dummy quiz ...)? Lastly how can I capture completion percentage upon suspend?

I don't think I am the only one trying to write these function. So I really don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there a library or helper functions for these?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me i finded t on internet while ago

```
 if( this.aiccgroup ) {
      LMSSetValue( this.name, lmsVal )
      if( this.name == 'cmi.score.raw' ){
        var scaled = this.value / 100
        LMSSetValue( 'cmi.score.scaled', scaled )
        LMSSetValue( 'cmi.score.min', 0 )
        LMSSetValue( 'cmi.score.max', 100 )
        LMSCommit( "" );
      }
```

it worked.

[visit this link complete view... i got this on solution on here](https://community.trivantis.com/forums/topic/manually-setting-cmi-score-min-and-cmi-score-max-in-lms/)